# Planar linkage that traces a circle from its exterior?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, classical-mechanics, plane-geometry

> ***Q***.
>   Is there a linkage in the plane that traces out a circle $C$
>   in such a manner that the interior of the disk bounded
>   by $C$ is never intersected by any link througout the motion?

What I mean by "a linkage in the plane" is best illustrated
by the famous [Peaucellier linkage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peaucellier%E2%80%93Lipkin_linkage), which traces out
a straight line segment:
<sub>(Wikipedia image.)</sub>

 
 
 
 
 [image: WikipediaPeacellier]

Some vertices are "pinned to the plane."
All vertex joints are universal in the sense
of allowing full $360^\circ$ motion.
All links are rigid segments, which can pass over one
another in a physical, layered model, e.g.,

 
 
 
 
 [image: HowRound]

 
 
 
 
 
<sub>(Image from [this *How Round Is Your Circle* web page](http://web.mat.bham.ac.uk/C.J.Sangwin/howroundcom/straightline/exact.html).)</sub>

---

Of course it is trivial without the restriction that the
links not intersect the interior of $C$: One radial link
pinned to the center of $C$ suffices.
And the challenge in the
Peaucellier linkage was to convert the natural
circular motions of linkage components into straight-line
motion.
Here I am seeking a vertex of the linkage
to follow a natural circular motion,
but with the restriction to not intersect
the interior of that circle $C$.
Following a subarc of $C$—say, a semicircle—without
intersecting the interior of $C$, would also be quite interesting.

It may be that the 19th-century masters (Peaucellier, Lipkin, Watt, Chebyshev, et al.)
did not investigate this question.
But perhaps there is an easy construction I am not seeing...?

---

Here is a version of *TMA*'s idea. The pantograph shown scales by $\times 2$:
As joint $x$ traces arc $A$, endpoint $y$ traces arc $B$, from the exterior of
$B$'s disk:

 
 
 
 
 [image: PantographArc]

Comment: what comes to mind is lens polishing, the surfaces of lenses for telescopes having generally had a spherical face.

Comment: @WillJagy: Cool connection, Will! With that hint I found several patents for lens polishing mechanisms, each impenetrable to me (although with limited time investment).

Comment: I think if you go back far enough in history there will be something understandable. Note that the ideal face of a lens with flat on the other side is actually a hyperboloid of revolution, at least for one fixed wavelength of light. For parabolic mirrors, one thing they are doing is making giant rotating baths of mercury, to get a perfect parabolic surface for large optical telescope. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_mirror_telescope

Comment: You say "Following a subarc would also be interesting." But that is what Peaucellier linkage does if you move the fixed end of blue segment a bit from the other fixed join (the end of two green segments). [On the second picture you need to choose the hole on the right.]

Comment: @AntonPetrunin: You are right, just drawing an arc from its exterior is not that difficult or interesting; my misjudgement. But drawing a large portion, or all of a circle, still seems challenging.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a facility with graphics; hopefully the verbal description below will work.

There is a linkage that magnifies: place a tracing stylus at point P, a marking stylus at
point Q, and this linkage M will allow one to trace a figure and replicate it with a growth
factor of (say) 3.

Now take M and attach it to a pivoting link with the free end fixed to P in such a way that Q traces an arc.  One can get at least 
120 degrees of arc this way, and arrange it so the arc is convex from the side of the combined linkage.
For a full circle, a link arm has to be transported around a point and be rotated at least 180 degrees during this journey.  I am confident a linkage can be designed,  but have no ideas for it at present.

Comment: My mental picture suggests 7 links, 2 fixed pivots and six nonfixed.  If one "fully extends" the linkage, one can approach 180 degrees of arc from below.  I don't see how to extend this to get past 180 without crossing the interior.

Comment: Also, the linkage I picture is like that of Peaucellier, with the internal three links reversed as well as shortened, and attached to the middle of the two long links.

Comment: Very nice idea! I've illustrated a version of it, using a pantograph as the enlarging mechanism. I did not try to compute (or illustrate) the largest arc angle achievable.

Comment: Thank you for this solution, I have been looking for a mechanism like this. However, how would one go about building this to be 10x instead of 2x for example? I can not scale it for some reason, must be missing something.